# Condicional if no entra despues de ejecutar una funcion swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

en swiftUI tengo un **Button** que ejecuta una función que se encarga de registrar un nuevo usuario, todo perfecto, tengo lo siguiente:

```
Button {
   self.rModel.makeRegistro()

   if self.rModel.regDone {
     self.showDone = true
   } label: { Text("Crear Cuenta") }
}
```

*rModel* es un model view donde esta la función y dos variables *published*, **regDone** y **clienteData** ambos reciben la data sin problemas, cuando **regDone** es true pasamos a true la variable **showDone** que nos envía a una vista con los resultados del registro, el problema es que después de ejecutar la función ***makeRegistro()*** la condicional no funciona, es decir, no muestra la vista, en cambio, si coloco un **print** después de la condicional si muestra la vista, esa vista la llamo de la siguiente manera:

```
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $showDone) {
   DoneView(clienteData: self.rModel.clienteData)
}
```

Como puedo solucionar ese problema sin colocar un print para que aparezca la vista, debo aclarar que estoy dando mis pininos con swift y no encuentro información de este tipo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo mas probable es que estas lidiando con con algo asynchronous en `makeRegistro` y estas esperando resultados sincronizados necesitas solution eso. Si puedes mira "Meet async/await" de WWDC.